# Equivalent of format function of Python in PHP

Tags: php, python

Python background, and the 'format' function used to be so handy to me. 
I have this following toString in Python for the famous Fraction class:

```
def __str__(self):
    """
    Return a user friendly form for the fraction. 
    :return: str 
    """ 
    return "{}/{}".format(self.numerator, self.denominator)
```

Java has a very similar one and I need something equivalent for the PHP, does it have a similar format function?

Comment: Check out [`sprintf`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php)

Comment: You could also use string concatenation or `"$numerator/$denominator"`

Comment: Hey Adam, you never selected any of the provided answers as *accepted* (the green tick mark). Please do so in order to mark this question as solved. The same goes for all your other questions (with answers).

Answer (score 2):

**I think you might be looking for [`sprintf`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php)**

> `string sprintf ( string $format [, mixed $args [, mixed $... ]] )`
>   Returns a string produced according to the formatting string format.

Example:

```
$numerator = 1.570796327;
$denominator = 0.5;

$format = '%g/%g';
echo sprintf($format, $numerator, $denominator);
```

Result:

```
1.5708/0.5
```

Check the [**Parameters**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php#refsect1-function.sprintf-parameters) section of the documentation for a full synopsis on the format options.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely looking for sprintf

```
$whole = 100;
$decimal = 50;

$fullNumber = sprintf("%d.%d", $whole, $decimal);
echo $fullNumber;
```